# Problem when trying to add a value to multiple columns in diferrent tables in SQL using php and html

Tags: php, mysql, sql

So i am trying to create a project with phpmyadmin, php and html to register new products with only one category assigned to each product and then view them. I have 2 tables. The first one is "products" and it has id, name, quantity and CATEGORY_ID, while the second one is "product_category" and it has CATEGORY_ID and c_name.

The primary keys at these tables are the id and CATEGORY_ID accordingly. I have made a relation between products and product_category 1-n (a category can have many products, but a product can have only one category), and the CATEGORY_ID of the products table is a foreign key. The products.id and the product_category.CATEGORY_ID are "auto increment".

I have the following issues:
when i create a new product I want the products.CATEGORY_ID to be filled automatically from the product_category.CATEGORY_ID. If the products.CATEGORY_ID isn't filled automatically (when i try to create a product) then I will not be able to join the 2 tables and display at one table the name, quantity and c_name.

If you have any other solution to display in one table the name, quantity and c_name let me know. Thank you!

i tried to add the following in the create.php but with no luck

```
$mpla1 = "INSERT INTO product (CATEGORY_ID) VALUES (SELECT CATEGORY_ID FROM product_category WHERE (c_name = '$c_name'))";
```

create.php:

```
if ( !empty($_POST)) {
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $quantity = $_POST['quantity'];
    $c_name = $_POST['c_name'];



    // create a product
    $pdo = Database::connect();
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $sql = "INSERT INTO product (name,quantity) values (?,?)";
    $mpla = "INSERT INTO product_category (c_name) values (?)";


    //$sql = "INSERT INTO product (name,quantity) values (?,".$quantity.")";
    $q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $q->execute(array($name,$quantity));
    $result = $pdo->prepare($mpla);
    $result->execute(array($c_name));

    $mpla1 = "INSERT INTO product (CATEGORY_ID) VALUES (SELECT CATEGORY_ID FROM product_category WHERE (c_name = '$c_name'))";





    //$q->execute(array($name));
    Database::disconnect();
    header("Location: index.php");}
```

index.php

//missing the scripts here

```
    <table border="1" cellpadding="10">
        <tr align='center'>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Quantity</th>
            <th>Category</th>
            <th>Action</th>

        </tr>
        <form id="viewFrom" method="POST">
        <input type="hidden" id="productId" name="productId" value=""/>
          <?php
           include 'database.php';
           $pdo = Database::connect();
           $sql = 'SELECT * FROM product INNER JOIN product_category ON (product.CATEGORY_ID = product_category.CATEGORY_ID)';
           foreach ($pdo->query($sql) as $row) {
                    echo "<tr align='center'>";
                    echo '<td>'. $row['name'] . '</td>';
                    echo '<td>'. $row['quantity'] . '</td>';
                    echo '<td>'. $row['c_name'] . '</td>';
                    echo '<td><button type="button" onclick="viewProduct('.$row['id'].')">view</button><button type="button" onclick="updateProduct('.$row['id'].')">update</button><button type="button" onclick="deleteProduct('.$row['id'].')">delete</button></td>';
                    echo '</tr>';
           }
           Database::disconnect();
          ?>
          </form>
    </table>
    <form id="createFrom" action="create.html" method="POST">
        <button type="submit">create</button>
    </form>
</body>
```

create.html

```
<form id="updateFrom" action="create.php" method="POST">
    <table border="1" cellpadding="10">
        <tr align='center'>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td><input name="name" type="text" value=""/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr align='center'>
            <td>Quantity</td>
            <td><input name="quantity" type="text" value=""/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr align='center'>
            <td>Category</td>
            <td><input name="c_name" type="text" value=""/></td>
        </tr>

    </table>
    <button type="submit">create</button>
    </form>
```

Comment: You haven't told us the error you got nor the definitions for your tables. I suspect that column CATEGORY_ID in table product is defined as NOT NULL (it should be, anyway) in which case the first insert must fail. Also, the way your code is structured, you could easily end up with multiple rows in table product_category having the same value for c_name in which case `SELECT CATEGORY_ID FROM product_category WHERE (c_name = '$c_name')` will return multiple values, which will be fatal.

Comment: weird thing is i dont get any errors. i can view the table created in the index.php but either i will see the name and quantity values under or the category name. for example using   ' $sql = 'SELECT * FROM product LEFT JOIN product_category ON (product.CATEGORY_ID = product_category.CATEGORY_ID)'; '

Comment: But the true problem is i dont think SELECT CATEGORY_ID FROM product_category WHERE (c_name = '$c_name') works when i create a new product

Comment: Where do you prepare and execute `$mpla1`. Also never put PHP variables into SQL string.

Comment: I just added `$category = $pdo->prepare($sql);
  $category->execute(array($CATEGORY_ID));` . Should I put them underneath `$mpla1 = "INSERT INTO product (CATEGORY_ID) VALUES (SELECT CATEGORY_ID FROM product_category WHERE (c_name = '$c_name'))";` ? Im very new to this and I dont know queries automatically execute. Also what would you advise me to use instead of `$c_name` inside `$mpla1 = "INSERT INTO product (CATEGORY_ID) VALUES (SELECT CATEGORY_ID FROM product_category WHERE (c_name = '$c_name'))";` ?